# send email based on account type

Tags: class

when ever account type is changed form any value to 'Customer' need to 
send an email to account owner saying your account become customer 
and create a task and assign it to account owner.

Comment: please share what you have tried alongside your specific problem, show a minimum level of effort before posting. additionally, take some time to read [Ask] and take the [tour] and update your post accordingly. Thanks

Comment: trigger accountype on Account (before insert, before update) {
    for(Integer i = 0 ; i < Trigger.new.size() ; i++){
      if(Trigger.new[i].Type =='Customer')
          
   }   
}

Comment: public with sharing class emailnotify  {
    //static method
    public static List<Account> sendEmail(List<Account> Accounts) {

        //query on template object
        EmailTemplate et=[Select id from EmailTemplate where name=:'Sales: New Customer Email'];

        //list of emails
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new

Comment: List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

        //loop
        for(Account Acc : aCCOUNTS){

            //check for Account
            if(Acc.Id == null && Acc.Email != null){

Comment: //initiallize messaging method
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage singleMail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

                //set object Id
                singleMail.setTargetObjectId(Acc.Id);

                //set template Id
                singleMail.setTemplateId(et.Id);

                //flag to false to stop inserting activity history
                singleMail.setSaveAsActivity(false);

                //add mail
                emails.add(singleMail);

Comment: //This will not send email to contact  
               emails.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false);
            }
        }

        //send mail
        Messaging.sendEmail(emails);

        return Account;
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a workflow whenever any account is updated, add a criteria whenever the field value changes to 'customer', create a workflow action and send the email to Account Owner and add one more action of creating a task, and in the 'Assigned To' field, choose the value of the Account Owner.

Comment: +1 although you can send a notification of the task, so the workflow email may not even be necessary.

Comment: i want to do it using apex class or triggers .please can you help me out with that

Comment: He has to notify that the customer that the value has been changed. But the task notification contains details regarding the task only.

Comment: thanks , can't we acheive it using apex class or triggers